# Filtering in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, filter, tuples

What I would like to do is take in a list of tuples and then check if any element in any of the tuples matches an int. If the int matches either element in the tuple then the tuple is added to the list to be returned.
Once the list has scanned through all of the tuples it will return a list of tuples which only match the int.

```
filter1 :: (a -> Bool) -> [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)]  
filter1 _ [] = []  
filter1 p (x:xs)   
    | p x       = x : filter1 p xs  
    | otherwise = filter1 p xs
```

Here is what I have so far. The only problem is where it re-curses I get an error because I am taking a list of tuples and putting it back into a place that should just be an int.

Comment: All you've done here is repeated the definition of `filter`, but you've changed the type signature.  However, you haven't changed the type signature quite enough.  Try `filter1 :: ((Int, Int) -> Bool) -> [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)]`.

Comment: Here, each `x` has type `(Int, Int)`, and you want to apply a function to it that returns a boolean.  Thus, your `p` function has to have the type `(Int, Int) -> Bool`.  The type of `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` is telling here.  You take a list of `a`s and a function from `a` to `Bool`.  Here you're passing in a list of `(Int, Int)`, so `a` is `(Int, Int)`.

Comment: @bheklilr I've tried this already and it didn't work for me

Comment: In what way did it not work?  You also say that you're getting an error, but have not said what the error really easy.  Please post the full text of the error messages you're getting, GHC's errors are usually actually very informative and good for solving type errors.

Comment: Error - Type error in application
expression filter1 (5,6) [(5,6),(7,8)]
term (5,6)
type (a,b)
Does not match (Int, Int) -> Bool

Comment: @Sprout ``(5, 6)`` is not of type ``(Int, Int) -> Bool`` but of type ``(Int, Int)``. You have to pass a **function**, not just a "thing". How does a function taking a tuple of ``Int``s look? Well lets look at ``==``: ``==`` has type ``a -> a -> Bool`` where a must be equatable. So now we specialise ``==`` for ``(Int, Int)``: ``(Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> Bool``. But this is one tuple too much. How can we get rid of it? We could **partially apply** ``==`` (look it up if you have to, you need it).

Comment: @Sprout So we feed it some value (for example ``(5, 6)``: ``(== (5, 6))`` now is of type ``(Int, Int) -> Bool``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will give you some console output from GHCI, if you do not mind.

The type signature for `filter` is:

```
Prelude> :t filter
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

in other words, filter is a function which takes two arguments: the first is a function from any type `a` to the type `Bool`, the next is a list of `a` elements. It then gives you a list of `a` elements (those for which the function sends back `True`).

Your example code where you're trying `filter1 (5, 6) [(5, 6), (7, 8)]` is *almost* right and should instead read:

```
Prelude> filter (\x -> x == (5, 6)) [(5, 6), (7, 8)]
[(5, 6)]
```

We can write that predicate using a special syntax Haskell has for operators. Take any operator, let's call it `*+` for this explanation's sake; then `(*+)` is the same as `\x y -> x *+ y` and `(a *+)` is the same as `\y -> (a *+ y)` and `(*+ b)` is the same as `\x -> x *+ b`. So we can write the above filtering condition as simply `((5,6) ==)`, and we can make your example code work by defining:

```
Prelude> let filter1 val = filter (val ==)
Prelude> :t filter1
filter1 :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
Prelude> filter1 (5, 6) [(5, 6), (7, 8)]
[(5,6)]
```

*However* this is not quite what you asked. What you asked was to *take in a list of tuples and then check if any element in any of the tuples matches an int*. To do this we need to take in the int, too:

```
Prelude> let tfilter n = filter (\(a, b) -> a == n || b == n)
Prelude> :t tfilter
tfilter :: Eq a => a -> [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)]
Prelude> tfilter 3 [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]
[(2,3),(3,4)]
```

Comment: How would this be written as a function?

    tfilter :: Eq a => a -> [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)]
    tfilter n = filter (\(a, b) -> a == n || b == n)
             | otherwise = :t tfilter??

Comment: The `:t tfilter` is a GHCI command: "tell me the type of `tfilter`". The definition of `tfilter` appears above; in a `.hs` file you would simply write: `tfilter n = filter (\(a, b) -> a == n || b == n)`.

Answer (score 0):

**The Arrow Way :**

```
filter :: ( a -> Bool ) -> [ (Int, Int) ] -> [ (Int, Int) ]
```

Lets **generate** the filter predicate  `( (Int, Int) -> Bool )`,

`&&&` can be used to give a `( Int -> Bool, Int -> Bool )`.

For instance,

`( (==) &&& (==) ) 3` will yield `( (==3), (==3) )`

Those two partials can be passed to `***` by uncurrying it.

`( uncurry (***) ) ( (==3), (==3) )` will yield `( (==3) *** (==3) )`

This resulting Arrow can be used to test with our tuple values,

`( (==3) *** (==3) ) (4,3)` will yield `(False, True)`

then, by uncurrying `(||)`, we get a function that takes a tuple of booleans and gives its Logical OR.

`( uncurry (||) ) (False, True)` will yield `True`

Now we end up with this:

`f n tup = uncurry (||) $ ( uncurry (***) . ((==) &&& (==)) ) n tup`

To make a delay in composition of `uncurry (||)` until rest of 
partials `( uncurry (***) . ((==) &&& (==)) )` gets applied to `n` and `tup`:

`f = (uncurry (||) .) . uncurry (***) . ((==) &&& (==))`

Thats it.

`f 3 (4,5)` => `False`,

`f 3 (4,3)` => `True`.

Now we can use f predicate with filter to get the desired result.

`tfilter = filter . f`

or

`tfilter = filter . (uncurry (||) .) . uncurry (***) . ((==) &&& (==))`

`tfilter 3  [ (x,y) | x<-[3..6], y<-[1..4] ]`

=> `[(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(4,3),(5,3),(6,3)]`